# Sending email with outlook at a particular date, using VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am working a macro of **sending outlook emails** using excel VBA.  i have got the first step of sending an email out to different recipients. My code:

```
Sub SetRecipients()
Dim aOutlook As Object
Dim aEmail As Object
Dim rngeAddresses As Range, rngeCell As Range, strRecipients As String

Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)

Set rngeAddresses = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A13")
For Each rngeCell In rngeAddresses.Cells
strRecipients = strRecipients & ";" & rngeCell.Value
Next

aEmail.Importance = 2

aEmail.Subject = "Indicator activity warning ( TestMailSend )"

aEmail.Body = "Hi"

'aEmail.ATTACHMENTS.Add ActiveWorkbook.Book2.xlsx

aEmail.To = strRecipients

aEmail.Send

End Sub
```

**My objective:** is to be able to set a number of **different dates** that this email will be sent automatically.

**The Problem:** i am not sure how this can work

Comment: Simple Solution create a hidden sheet, where you input the dates, then on workbook activate you can look through the range of dates and if it satisfies, you can send email.

Comment: Please clarify how you want to use this in practice. If it's ok for you to open the excel sheet every day and it's ok to send the messages at the time of opening it, @PaulFrancis approach will work.

Comment: @nhee in practice , the user will input the dates they want the email to be sent. The ideal will be for this macro to run  when workbook closed or open.

Comment: I would suggest using the `Open` event instead of `Activate`, just to reduce the number of times the code will fire, but otherwise, go with the @PaulFrancis approach. Have the user set the dates on a sheet (hidden or not). Your code would loop through all dates, if it finds one that equals today's date, fire `SetRecipients()`, delete that date from the list (or move it to a `Sent` sheet, if you want to keep track of what was done). If you want to get fancy, use the Win Task Scheduler to automatically open the spreadsheet each day, then your code can close Excel when it's done running.

Comment: I would also suggest renaming `SetRecipients()` since it does so much more than just setting the recipients.

Comment: I will try the above

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are interested in the [DeferredDeliveryTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.deferreddeliverytime.aspx) property of Outlook items (MailItem). It allows to set a DateTime indicating the date and time the mail message is to be delivered.

You may find the [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) article helpful.